# Is there a way to increase the range at which I can lock on to enemies?

Tags: demons-souls

Enemy archers in Demon's Souls will see me and start shooting at me from really far away. Is the range at which I can lock on to them increased by a stat or is there a ring that would increase the lock distance?

Comment: I think the lock-on range is related to the range rating of the equipped bow. It's not equal to the actual range though, since you can shoot further using the aim mode. The White Bow has the highest range rating. There doesn't appear to be any rings which affect the lock-on distance.

Comment: So, if I don't have a bow at all, there isn't really any sort of recourse then. That stinks.

Comment: If you're wearing a Thief Ring the enemies won't be able to see you until you are much closer, so they won't fire at you from really far away anymore. Perhaps that's your best solution?

Comment: Actually I think perhaps I'm wrong about the link between the bow and the lock-on range...

Comment: +1 for YellowMegaMan as that's the closest to an actual answer so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Lock range never increases. The best you can do is use the Thief Ring so that you can get closer to enemies before they spot you.